# Use Pantheios logging framework from a dll

Tags: c++, dll, logging, pantheios

Im a trying to use pantheios logging framework from inside a c++ dll. I have successfully built the dll and it executes through my test application (C++ MFC Application).

I have used implicit linking with the following includes:

```
#include <pantheios/implicit_link/core.h>
#include <pantheios/implicit_link/fe.simple.h>
#include <pantheios/implicit_link/be.console.h>
```

My DllMain initializes pantheios with the following calls:

```
extern "C" const char PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY[] = "FinishingLineController";

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved)
    {
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            {
            int panres =  pantheios::pantheios_init(); 

            if(panres < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise the Pantheios libraries: %s\n", 
                        pantheios::pantheios_getInitErrorString(panres));

                return FALSE;
            }
            }
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            pantheios::pantheios_uninit();
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

When I execute the following code I get an

`Microsoft C++ exception: stlsoft::winstl_project::windows_exception at memory location 0x0013da84`

```
pantheios::log_DEBUG("Test logging");
```

I have tried to use explicit linking instead without any result.

Comment: Wow! 7 hours and no response. I was waiting with baited breath for this question to be answered as I face the same problem. I do have a link to http://sourceforge.net/projects/pantheios/forums/forum/647484/topic/1639420, where a similar question was posed, but haven't tried it to see if it would work. Joakim, if the link helps, then let me know, I will find time to try it myself.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information to explain the problem. Are you simply using Pantheios within a DLL, or are you exporting its functionality from the DLL? (btw, the Pantheios team have asked you for more information on the project forum where you reported the issue: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pantheios/forums/forum/475314/topic/3407328?message=7642468)

Comment: The problem turned out to be non pantheios related. I have provided an answer of my own with the solution I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some further tests showed that the logging from the dll works if I link it to a console application instead of a windows application. And if I change the backend to "file" instead of "console" the windows application do log correctly to the file. So the problem seem to be that the windows application doesn't have a "console".

The solution was to redirect standard output/input pipes to a new console. This has to be done for a win32 application since a console is not created by default.

```
void RedirectIOToConsole()
{
    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    FILE *fp;

    // allocate a console for this app
    AllocConsole();

    // set the screen buffer to be big enough to let us scroll text
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = MAX_CONSOLE_LINES;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);

    // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "r" );
    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stderr = *fp;
    setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // make cout, wcout, cin, wcin, wcerr, cerr, wclog and clog
    // point to console as well
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio();
}
```

And then call this function from DllMain.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        RedirectIOToConsole();

        int panres =  pantheios::pantheios_init();  

        if(panres < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise the Pantheios libraries: %s\n", 
                    pantheios::pantheios_getInitErrorString(panres));

            return FALSE;
        }

        // Set the file name for all back-ends.
        //pantheios_be_file_setFilePath("output.log");
    }
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    pantheios::pantheios_uninit();
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is it a coincidence that someone named Timo Geusch solved a same/similar problem with pantheios this week with same solution? http://codeblog.bsdninjas.co.uk/index.php?/archives/134-Using-pantheios-to-log-inside-a-C++-JNI-DLL.html. Any suggestions for me, since I use an MFC DLL, which does not have a DllMain but has an InitInstance()? Would the same procedure apply?

Answer (score 3):

AFAICT, your codes looks complete and correct, but it's hard to know how you're using it, and from where, and when exactly you get the exception. I think you should provide more information.

One thing I woul d say: you might want to use [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/)'s internal logging "[bailout](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/namespacepantheios_1_1util.html#c66a42a6ea897eb1d4b48124dd4499fb)" functionality - a log for the log, I suppose. So, your

```
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise the Pantheios libraries: %s\n",
    pantheios::pantheios_getInitErrorString(panres));
```

would be better written as

```
pantheios::util::onBailOut(pantheios::emergency,
    "Failed to initialise the Pantheios libraries",
    PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY,
    pantheios::getInitErrorString(panres));
```

That way your log-initialization failure will itself be logged.

Comment: Thanks for the "bailout"-function tips. Good to know.

The problem turned out to be non pantheios related. I have provided an answer of my own with the solution I found.